# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

Thank you in advance, Does someone can help me?
Here are the error message

I got invalid argument with below function when I use the data from my ConfigFileParser.py.

```
class TestLogin:
config = ConfigFileParser('login.ini')

def test_login(self, setup):
    self.driver = setup
    self.driver.get(self.config.getUrl())
```

ConfigFileParser.Py

```
class ConfigFileParser:
cfgFileDir = 'TestData'
config = configparser.ConfigParser()

def __init__(self, cfg):
    self.cfgFile = cfg
    self.base_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    self.config_file = self.base_dir.joinpath(self.cfgFileDir).joinpath(self.cfgFile)
    self.config.read(self.config_file)

def getUrl(self):
    return self.config['login']['uatenv']
```

[image]

Comment: Your indentation seems off, but maybe that happened when you were copying the code to the question? Also, where does the error point to in your code? The whole stack trace would be more helpful than the specific error.

Comment: Yes. it's because the copy for indentaion.

Comment: self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x0455CEF0>
response = {'status': 400, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"invalid argument","message":"invalid argument\\n  (Session info: chrome=1...\n\\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E57B5E+286]\\n\\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E57B2E+238]\\n"}}'}
 here is the message